# Samsung Galaxy S3 choosing contact for text..takes forever to come up

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

When I am sending a text and i type in the name for the contact it takes several mins for the contact for to come up..this is very aggravating when you need to send a text fast..how to i fix this????

Comment: What version of Android are you running, this seems to be a 'feature' of Samsung devices at times. What text app are you using, default or hangouts?

Answer (score 1):

If your contacts are stored on a SD card you may have a faulty SD card. Try moving your contacts to the device storage or sync them to your Google contacts.